Python - Need way for property address validation and clean up
I'm looking for a way to validate a number of property addresses and clean them up to be searched for in a list of addresses we have. We have many people send in requests to get funds from their loan for fix and flip properties and I need to notify them that they were received. The address is user inputted and does not always match our records 100%. Such as:
Borrower input:
123 N Man St., Tx
Our record:
123 North Main Street, Dallas, Texas
There could be typos or simplified naming in the input.
Is there a Python module or package to take this string and clean it up to be searched for in a list of addresses? I need them to find the borrower email in the list to send them a notification that the request has been received. I have everything figured out except for how to clean up the address and/or validate that it is real.
Would love some help or advice!

That is a hard problem. Not sure if there is a Python 3rd party package whcih could help there, but for "real world" needs of this, I've always used Google Maps API.  (And it is hard to deal with it as well - one always has to double-check the resulting address, using some other parameter)
